# Failed to code sign.. / No codesigning identities

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Currently making a push apns. p12 and provisioning profile has received from the supplier. After installing the p12, install a provisioning profile was run xcode. This error occurred.

Failed to code sign "Sample App".
No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“Provisioning XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX”) were found.
Xcode can attempt to fix this issue.

code signing-> provisioning profile is selected -> code sign identity is selected -> No identities from Profile "provisioning profile name ~ ~" is shown .This occurs in different provisioning file certificate and key chains suitable . I do not know why but it just should not.

Comment: check your keychain is added the valid .p12 or not

Comment: thank you. I've check, p12 file is valid

Comment: the .p12 is added with your private key are you sure

Comment: Certainly use the private key that matches the certificate on p12.

Comment: recheck the profile selection in BuildSettings of Project, and all targets (include test)